# Can concrete screws or the holes be reused?

Tags: concrete, screws

So we drilled into concrete to bolt down steel bases with several [Titen 3/8" x 3" Titen heavy duty Screw Anchor](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/395ea190-9e26-4093-9349-d31bd239b939/svn/simpson-strong-tie-masonry-concrete-anchors-thd37300h-64_1000.jpg).

I'll be replacing the base, so I will need to remove the screw, remove the base, and then re-bolt the new base to the concrete. I will probably use new screws, but can I reuse the hole? I would be using the same exact screw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [information on the manufacturer's web site](https://www.strongtie.com/mechanicalanchors_mechanicalanchoringproducts/thd_anchor/p/titen-hd#ProductDetails), they are careful to say not to re-use the fastener, but they do not specifically say not to re-use the hole.

I am a bit surprised and even find it odd that Simpson, whose instructions and product information is usually very thorough, would leave this in a gray area.

I personally would not re-use the hole if you need to rely on these fasteners delivering their rated pullout value.  To be honest, I have used lots of this type of fastener and I find them very convenient to use, but I don't have great confidence in them.
 If you wobble a little when drilling a hole in masonry, it's going to be a little oversized, and that could significantly weaken the hold of this kind of anchor.

If you just need it to resist shear, I would not worry about it.  If pullout strength is critical, you could easily re-drill the hole bigger for use with a different type of anchor.

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on how loose the hole was to begin with and what damage occurred when you removed the screw. Concrete is unforgiving of abrasion, so when you install and remove a screw you grind away material.

If the pullout loads aren't huge for what you're doing I'd run them in and see if they grab. If you have a lot of pull on them, maybe add epoxy when you reinstall to improve grip.